# Good Alternative to Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, crystal-reports

We're upgrading a bunch of computers in our office to x64 machines running Windows 7.
The problem is that Crystal Reports behaves badly when run on a 64 bit OS. Apparently it doesn't have any 64 bit initializers? ([Crystal Reports Runtime for VS on Windows 7 Throws an Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460264/crystal-reports-runtime-for-vs-on-windows-7-throws-an-error) for reference)

I tried Windows report viewer, but it looks even more clunky than Crystal Reports. You either have to report from only one table at a time, or you have to create a view for each report, and it looks like the report has to be table based? (instead of a freeflow page layout like Crystal has)

All our reports are in Crystal format, but I'm willing to rewrite them if it gives me a way to have them be less clunky, and work on 64bit computers without a hacky workaround.

Comment: I've seen in action Telerik' tool: http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx and it seems a nice alternative. You can give it a try for free.

Comment: Active Reports is another most-reputable vendor in this space. http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ActiveReports/Features.aspx They seem to provide migration support too, which means their library could convert your existing crystal reports files in to their format.  But my heart still stays with Crystal Reports :) Not sure why X86 workaround does not worked for you as you mentioned in your other thread. (But my guess is that you might have set X86 only for Debug mode and not for release mode).  Cheers.

Comment: @Karthik - If I can get crystal reports to work correctly I'm happy to stay with it. It does work well for what it is. In Advance Compile Options I have the Target CPU set to x86, and in the Configuration manager, both Debug and Release have x86 set as the platform. If I'm doing it wrong, I'd love for you to tell me the right way. Granted, once I install CR x86 manually, and the rest of the project prerequisites, then install the project by clicking the .application file instead of setup.exe, it works like it's supposed to. It's just a pain to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get Crystal Reports to work in x64 mode compiled to Any CPU with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 (x64)

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/support?rid=/webcontent/uuid/d01fdad8-44e5-2d10-61ad-9d2d4158f3a8

Comment: Seriously, a downvote 4 years later with no comment to explain why it isn't a good answer any more?

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted, but your reply doesn't answer the question exactly. this should have been under comments but not as an answer. the topic is for getting suggestions on alternatives for crystal report so a straight forward answer is to suggest alternatives , your reply is more of a tip to make it work on 64 bit machine's thus tips belong in comments not in answer section.

Comment: @DharaniKumar I do see your point that it doesn't match the answer asked in the topic, but it does answer the problem in the question itself ("CR doesn't work on x64, is there something that does?"). I know it answers the question because I chose it as the answer to my question. Maybe I should just delete the whole question and everything as being 6 years out of date and poorly asked...